# Inserindo um alerta de navegação no Phonegap

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova

Olá Gente eu sou novo no phonegap, e por este motivo ainda tenho algumas dúvidas básicas. Estou escrevendo um código de exemplo para aparecer um alerta na aplicação, só que no momento em que eu vou compilar aparece o seguinte erro:
navigator.notification is undefined
Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Teste</h1>
<input type="button" id="alerta"value="Alerta" onClick="alerta()">
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function alerta() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'Phonegap está funcionando!',
            null,
            'Sucesso',
            'Fechar'
        );
    }

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Olhe isto e veja se lhe ajudar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627281/navigator-notification-alert-not-working-phonegap

Comment: Não ajudou muito.

Comment: Estás a utilizar o phonegap build, o cordova ou o phonegap?

Comment: Estou usando Phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

**navigator.notification.alert** é um comando de plugin. Mais especificamente, este aqui: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-dialogs

Para que ele funcione, você precisa registrar o plugin em seu projeto via CLI da seguinte maneira:

- Abra o terminal ou prompt de comando;
- Acesse a pasta raiz do seu projeto;
- Adicione o plugin com:  **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs** ou
  **phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs**;

Se você não fizer isso, vai precisar adicionar os requisitos manualmente, o que envolve alterar o arquivo config.xml, o cordova_plugins.js e adicionar pastas de javascript e linguagens nativas a cada plataforma do projeto. Portanto, tente trabalhar com o CLI desde o começo.

Espero que ajude. :)